# Magento advanced search returns no results

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7

My problem is, that the advanced search in magento returns no results (the normal search does). If I dump

```
$this->getLoadedProductCollection()
```

in my Template, it returns "null". So I looked at the class which sets the collection to the advanced search template/view in "app/code/local/Mage/CatalogSearch/Block/Advanced/Result.php" and found this method:

```
public function setListCollection() {
    $this->getChild('search_result_list')->setCollection($this->_getProductCollection());
}
```

If I dump

```
$this->_getProductCollection();
```

I get all products matching my search query. But why returns my first method null? I have no idea.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

If the products are there maybe you are not showing the block `search_result_list`.
Check your layout file `catalogsearch.xml` and see how the handle `<catalogsearch_advanced_result>` looks like. It should have a block inside it with the name `search_result_list`. Compare it to the one in the default theme. To make it easier, here it show it should look like:

```
<catalogsearch_advanced_result translate="label">
    <label>Advanced Search Result</label>
    <update handle="page_two_columns_right" />
    <!-- Mage_Catalogsearch -->
    <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/2columns-right.phtml</template></action>
    </reference>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="catalogsearch/advanced_result" name="catalogsearch_advanced_result" template="catalogsearch/advanced/result.phtml">
            <block type="catalog/product_list" name="search_result_list" template="catalog/product/list.phtml">
                <block type="catalog/product_list_toolbar" name="product_list_toolbar" template="catalog/product/list/toolbar.phtml">
                    <block type="page/html_pager" name="product_list_toolbar_pager"/>
                </block>
                <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>empty</layout><count>6</count></action>
                <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>one_column</layout><count>5</count></action>
                <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>two_columns_left</layout><count>4</count></action>
                <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>two_columns_right</layout><count>4</count></action>
                <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>three_columns</layout><count>3</count></action>
                <action method="setToolbarBlockName"><name>product_list_toolbar</name></action>
            </block>
            <action method="setListOrders"/>
            <action method="setListModes"/>
            <action method="setListCollection"/>
        </block>
    </reference>
</catalogsearch_advanced_result>
```

Comment: Thanks for your anwers but my XML looks exactly like yours :)

Comment: I know I'm annoying but are you sure this line is there `<action method="setListCollection"/>`. Also try reverting your theme to the default one and see if the issue is reproducing. You can also disable the custom modules one my one and see if one of them is causing the issue.

Comment: Yes, the <action> is there and in the right place. I replaced the current xml with the xml from the "base" folder but the same result

Comment: Hi emha, I have the same issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19386241/magento-1-8-advanced-search-doesnt-work