# Magento 1.8 - Advanced Search doesn't work

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.8

I have found a strange bug in the latest release of magento: Advanced Search tool doesn't work properly.

What have I done:

- Install a fresh copy of magento
- Added a product called Test 1 by the administration page
- Reindex all
- Cleared all caches
- At the frontend page:

  - Open the Advanced Search Page
  - Search the "Test 1" product that you have added before in the catalog

    - No result

I have no result using as search attribute the "Name" of the product.

Seems that another user has the same issue: [Magento advanced search returns no results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18587673/magento-advanced-search-returns-no-results)

If you see the entity table in the database, you can see the attribute "71" with the name of the product. Attribute 71 is the "Name" Magento Attribute.

**Catalog Product Varchar Attribute Backend Table**

[image: Catalog Product Varchar Attribute Backend Table]

If I try to read the Magento code at app/code/core/Mage/CatalogSearch/Model/Advanced.php and debug it, I can see this command:

```
$this->getProductCollection()->addFieldsToFilter($allConditions);

array(1) {
  ["catalog_product_entity_varchar"] => array(1) {
    [71] => array(1) {
      ["like"] => string(9) "%Test 1%"
    }
  }
}
```

but Magento doesn't show me any result.

**If I try to execute a search process using the SKU field, magento return the product!**

```
array(1) {
  ["catalog_product_entity"] => array(1) {
    ["sku"] => array(1) {
      ["like"] => string(6) "%test%"
    }
  }
}
```

Is a Magento Bug?

Update: If I add the default category to the list of the product categories, seems that it works. Is a normal Magento behaviour?

thanks

Comment: Hi @Michelangelo  I have same problem that you have explained, can you give some hint if you have solved it. thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is probably a bug in mysql 5.6 due to how the advanced search query is done. There is a work around in this bug report.

http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=70608